# How to Calulate ACU required by my Web APP

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-billing-api

I have a Web APP in Azure PAAS service App Service. App service plan uses a unit named as "ACU".
Is there any way by which i can calculate the number of ACU required by my web app.
As i have to do billing calculations so i need to prove that instance size chosen is based on some logical calulation.

Comment: There is not really a need to calculate the ACU, what you do is you change the size based on your need by monitoring the CPU and Memory and scaling up/down when needed. More information about ACU can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu
App Service is based on VMs

Comment: Daniel Bjork's answer is the correct one. Daniel, I recommend posting this as a response so that it can be upvoted. Other people searching for this answer will find it useful. I'd also mention autoscale rules in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

> Q. What is the Azure Compute Unit (ACU)?
>
> A. The concept of the Azure Compute Unit (ACU) provides a way of comparing compute (CPU) performance across Azure SKUs.
>
> The Azure Compute Unit (ACU) is used to help understand the
> relative compute performance between different Azure series and size
> VMs. It is based on the A0 (extra small) having a value of 50. A VM
> with an ACU of 100 has twice the compute of a VM with an ACU of 50. A
> VM with an ACU of 200 would be twice that of a VM with an ACU of 100
> and so on.

So you should analyse the **CPU Usage** and **Memory Usage**.

For seeing that, you can go to your app service-->Diagnose and solve problems-->Availability and Performance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is NOT just considering ACUs for scalability and cost.

So you can <kbd>Scale Up</kbd> and <kbd>Scale Out</kbd> your App Service for meeting the demands during peak use and getting the final cost.

**Vertical Scaling:** For scaling up, since you don't initially know what kind of VM should suffice, you can start with a basic or intermediate one (not a very powerful one). General purpose Type VMs (50-210 ACUs) suffice in most cases. Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-up

**Horizontal scaling:** It's good practice to also scale out your App service plan. You can autoscale and set up autoscaling rules or go the manual route.
Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started

Next you should monitor your CPU Usage and Memory Usage as suggested by Doris.
Additionally you can also go to Run History and see your usage:
[image]

Based on your findings you can tweak the number and kind of VMs you need.