# Azure app service plan obtain actual ACU usage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I have an EP1 app service plan that is hosting a function app.

The plan has 210ACU per month.

How do I find out how many of those I'm using?
(What happens if I run out?)

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Compute Unit (ACU) provides a way of comparing compute (CPU) performance across Azure SKUs**.

Here you should analyze the CPU Usage and Memory Usage by going to the Diagnose and Solve problems > Availability and Performance:

[image]

In this case, you can Scale Up and Scale Out the App Service for meeting the demands during peak hours or you can increase the number of instances count.

Please check this [SO Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71869418/16630138)  where I explained about  how Scale Up and Scale Out methodology works.

Also, you can create the [alerts using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor) for the app service on different quota exceeds like CPU usage, Memory Consumption, Request Failures, etc.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. I need the ACU number (in order to work out if I need to scale up or will run out of AppService), but the screen you describe gives a percentage which is meaningless because the measure "one CPU" is undefined. Furthermore, the amount of ACU is measured monthly but the screen you describe gives instantaneous usage of some imaginary CPU.

Comment: The screen gives only 24 hours of data, but I'm interested in monthly ACU as specified by the App Service Plan.

Comment: Hello @RichardBarraclough, As per this [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63554494/how-to-calulate-acu-required-by-my-web-app), We can calculate how many instances are using by our function app and ACU usage in terms of CPU and Memory usage because in the official documentation, mentioned is whatever the type of ACU is General-Purpose/High Performance Compute/Compute Optimized Unit - depends on the CPU-to-memory ratio. Please check!

Comment: And the price you will be paying is for Monthly only!

Comment: Please check this [reference](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/azure/azure-app-service-plan/) as states that > The hardware resources that are available (like memory, storage and the compute power) also depend on the pricing tier you select. One thing I should point out here is, in Azure compute (i.e CPU) performance is compared using something called Azure Compute Unit (ACU for short).

Comment: So it is _not_ possible to determine how many ACUs I have used out of my plan and how many are left?

Comment: In an ACUs we can't get the exact no of **ACUs** used we can measure by using the **CPU & Memory utilization %**. If your compute units are not sufficient Azure will recommend `scaleup` or `scaleout`.